# Loading next page from json data to listview (endless scroll)

Tags: android, endlessadapter

Everything is working smoothly, but when I scroll to the bottom of the list view the list view refreshes with the next page, and doesn't append to the bottom of the list view. How can I have so the new data gets placed beneath the current data?

**My Code**

```
        @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listView.getCount() - 1 - 1) {
                        CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER = CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER + 25;

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER + " - " + JSON_AFTER, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        GetBlogPost getBlogPost = new GetBlogPost();
                        getBlogPost.execute();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

private class GetBlogPost extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
        int responseCode;
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.website.com/" + SUBS[Integer.parseInt(SUB)] + "/.json?count=" + CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER + "&after=" + JSON_AFTER );

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            responseCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Unsuccessful HTTP response code: %d", responseCode));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Exception caught!", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Exception caught!", e);
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        mBlogData = result;
        handleAsyncResponse();
    }
}

private void handleAsyncResponse() {
    if (mBlogData != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonData = mBlogData.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray jsonChildren = jsonData.getJSONArray("children");
            mPostTitles = new String[jsonChildren.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonChildren.length(); i ++) {
                JSONObject children = jsonChildren.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject post = children.getJSONObject("data");

                JSON_AFTER = jsonData.getString("after");

                String title = post.getString("title");
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                mPostTitles[i] = title;

                Target.add(title);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Target);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        Target
                );

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Exception caught!", e);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Nothing to display!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from here

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>...
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

You should keep the adapter somewhere, after loading new json data, try to append it to the existing adapter and request invalidate the list view

Comment: How would I go about keeping the adapter somewhere else?

Comment: some thing like this

ListView lstView; 
ArrayList<String> Target = new ArrayList<String>(); 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lstView = getListView();
    lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);        
    lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    Target.add("hi");
    Target.add("hello");
   ;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, Target);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Target.add("myname");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}   
}

Comment: I replaced a few lines of code in the "HandleBlogResponse" class, but now when i scroll to the bottom, i get a null pointer exception. any idea why?

Comment: private adapter;
        loadListView() {
            initadapter()
        }
        dataincome() {
            pustdatatoadapter(adapter, data)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

Answer (score 0):

After getting data from JSON response update your adapter.

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Isnt that just checking if scroll to bottom too?

Comment: no  and also you can set number of item i means update listview when 3 item remaining or as you set

Comment: I already try this and this is woking fine...In my case I update listview after every 30 item load and new item added when I reach at 27th item in list